# efficient regression of multiple outputs in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, regression

Say I have predictor array `x=numpy.array(n,px)` and a predicted array `y=numpy.array(n, py)`
What would be the best way in python to calculate all regression (linear) from x to each dimension of y (1...py)?
The output of the whole thing would be a matrix (py, px) (for each output, px parameters).

I could of course easily iterate over outputs dimensions (for each computing normal single output multivariate input OLS), however that would be inefficient as I will recalculate the pseudo inverse matrix of x.

Is there any efficient implementation out there?
Could not find any (neither http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/OLS)

Comment: how does `y` correlate with `x`, in a general equation of the form:  `y = ax + b`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured `scikit-learn` would have done this already, so I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L304) and discovered that they use `scipy.linalg.lstsq` (see line 379).

According to [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html), the `scipy` version of `lstsq` does indeed accept a matrix as the `b` parameter. (Actually the [numpy version](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) accepts a matrix value as well.)

Maybe these are what you're looking for ?

Comment: Yeah, I did something similar: used `numpy.linalg.lstsq` ... The problem is this lacks the computation for p value and likelihood. I guess the wrapper of linear regression in scikit-learn should be updated to support multiple outputs in the future

Answer (score 0):

The fit() method of sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression accepts multi-target output, so this is now handled natively in sklearn. Just use a 2-dimensional array for the y value of fit(X,y) of shape (n_samples, n_targets).